# How to run an individual Django test in PyDev

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, pydev

PyDev makes it easy to run individual Python unit tests with a contextual menu: right click on the test name, **Run as** -> **Python Unit-test**.

In a Django project however, the same functionality cannot be used as the default test runner does not load the Django apps before running the tests (so we get an exception `AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.`).

It is possible with PyDev to run all tests in a Django project (right click on the project -> **Django** -> **Run Django Tests (manage.py test)**) but that can take quite some time for large projects. I would need a UI to call `manage.py test myapp.tests.FooTest.test_creation` directly.

Is there a way to run a single Django unit test in PyDev?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best bet here is to use pytest along with https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ (then, inside of PyDev go to the preferences `PyDev > PyUnit` and choose `Py.test` as the test runner).

With that in-place you should be able to run individual unit tests from PyDev.

i.e.: When in the editor with the test file open, use `Ctrl+Shift+Up` (or Down) to navigate to the test you want and then with the test name selected use `Ctrl+F9` (then `Enter` to run the test).

Alternatively you can just press `Ctrl+F9` and filter by typing the name of the method(s) you want to run.